# Full width background to column that is inside container [ Bootstrap 3 ]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I have two columns inside a container and I'm trying to add a background colour to a column that extends full width outside the container. Here's the mock up.

[image]

As you can see, the content inside the yellow background sits inside a column that is inside a column. How do I set the background colour so that it goes full width to left and works for all screens?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2>
               Project Name
            </h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="spage-intro">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="intro-excerpt">
               Vestibulum eu metus at tortor molestie dapibus. Nullam viverra est id metus facilisis, id finibus dolor finibus. Aenean id mi eu risus condimentum ullamcorper.
            </h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="the-content-wrapper">
               Vestibulum eu metus at tortor molestie dapibus. Nullam viverra est id metus facilisis, id finibus dolor finibus. Aenean id mi eu risus condimentum ullamcorper.Vestibulum eu metus at tortor molestie dapibus. Nullam viverra est id metus facilisis, id finibus dolor finibus. Aenean id mi eu risus condimentum ullamcorper.
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: add background color to class "spage-intro"

Comment: Do u want the output like u attached image?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Add css:

```css
.intro-excerpt{
    background-color: #f6cc08;
}
```

Comment: Actually the question is, the background color only for left side div, not for entire div.

Comment: intro-excerpt is with in the container.. so it does'nt go to left side of the screen.. so plz check my code as i have send!!

Comment: Okay i got it..thank you

Comment: ok.. Have u tried in local?

Answer (score 0):

Plz follow the below steps.. If anything not clear plz ask..

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 with-bg"></div>
```

**css**

```
.with-bg {
    position: static;
}
.with-bg::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 35.33%;
    background-color: #f6cc08;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does't work.

Comment: Why.. I did in my local.. how it does'nt work.. can u plz share the screen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shyLftr1/

Comment: 5mins plz i will check and send the solution

Comment: .spage-intro {
    position: relative;
}

Comment: .with-bg {
    position: static;
}

Comment: Plz add my entire code and check

Comment: No, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have u added my prev comments style.. Seems it doesn't added in your snippet?

Comment: It's a public fiddle you won't be able so see the changes. Is it working for you?

Comment: Seems its wrong.. but i have added the styles in browser inspect.. .spage-intro { position: relative; } , .with-bg { position: static !important; } .. its working fine.. plz add my below styles..